Ideal cross chain swaps

What will be the ideal scenario for swapping assets in different chains? It's not possible to transfer any asset to a different chain.
What if we make a separate token for the swap? Mint a token against the input token to buy the output asset on the desired chain.


Hi, I don't understand the last question. For the first it sounds like asking for opinion, but probably something like THORChain, native as possible. For second, it is possible unless you speak of another sense? Stargate are favoured by many currently, you can see an example Sushi cross chain swap using Stargate here: https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/blob/main/xSwap.py

Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. Maybe this will make more sense.
